# how can I make a server connect to another server in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

How can I make a server connect to another server in java

My program is replicated file system. So , I need the client to connect to the server in order to read or write in the text file. which is easy to implement throw TCP connection . but the problem is how can i make the server connect other servers to avoid conflicting in the text file.

I have read about multicast throw UDP connection. can I make the server have to kind of connection one using TCP with client and another connection using TCP to multicast request to other servers in the group  ?
Or if there are anther way to implement that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at group communication frameworks, such as jgroups. 
Look [here](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/user-advanced.html) for explanation on TCP transport.